# AngularJs module cofiguration using model and provider

Tags: angularjs

I have an application with a following structure:

***definition of model***

```
app.module("example").value("exampleModule", exampleModel)
```

***definition of service provider***

```
app.module("example").provider("exampleService" , function(){
    this.setConfigurationSetting = function (value) { 
        exampleModel.someSetting = value; 
    };
    this.$get = function (exampleService){
        return exampleService;
     }
}
```

I want to configure all the services using one model in app.config function using Provider:

```
app.config("exampleServiceProvider"){
    exampleServiceProvider.setConfigurationSetting(true);
}
```

Angular documentation says that in provider model defined in such way cannot be accessed.
Is there any suggested way of setting up configuration for model via provider in such case?

Comment: Why do you need that `value`? Can't you just make this a variable inside the provider?

Comment: There's a logic in services that have exampleModel injected. So i want it to be set up before it's getting injected. And the other thing is that I want to have a single configuration file setting up all modules.

Comment: Values are not available in the `config` phase. Only `provider`s and `constants` are. You have to use a provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks [Miszy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/704894/miszy) !
You're right! I've added model provider that configures private object before injected into services as a model.

Works great!